# Tween animation on a Canvas in a custom View

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I have a class that extends `View`, and I draw everything I need inside its canvas in the `onDraw()` method, something like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        synchronized (this) {
                float h = mHeight;
                float w = mWidth;

                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                float roadLine= (85.0f/100.0f)*h;

                canvas.drawBitmap(mTop, 0, roadLine-mTop.getHeight(), null);

                //this is what I'd like to animate
                canvas.drawBitmap(mSmoke);

        }
    }
```

How do I make an Animation (tween animation) draw in here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't draw an `ImageView` inside the `onDraw()` method of another class.

This is probably more what you're after.

```
public class SimpleAnimation extends Activity {

Sprite sprite;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    setContentView(sprite);
}

class Sprite extends ImageView {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    Paint paint;
    RotateAnimation rotate;
    AlphaAnimation blend;
    ScaleAnimation scale;
    AnimationSet spriteAnimation;

    float centerX;
    float centerY;
    float offsetX;
    float offsetY;

    public Sprite(Context context) {
        super(context);

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        offsetX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        offsetY = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (spriteAnimation == null) {
            centerX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
            centerY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;
            createAnimation(canvas);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, centerX - offsetX, centerY - offsetY, paint);
    }

    private void createAnimation(final Canvas canvas) {

        rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, centerX, centerY);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        scale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 2, 0, 2, centerX, centerY);
        scale.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        scale.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        scale.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

        spriteAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
        spriteAnimation.addAnimation(rotate);
        spriteAnimation.addAnimation(scale);
        spriteAnimation.setDuration(10000L);

        startAnimation(spriteAnimation);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 'TerrorizedBus' is my 'Activity' and I use it there to get the 'Context'

Comment: Ok. But then how do I animate it?

Comment: @iuliux.  I expanded my answer for you.  Hope it helps.  Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Yes, the second option would be what I was looking for. Actually I've already tried this but I couldn't place that smokeView on my canvas to start it animate.

Comment: You can't place a `View` on a `Canvas`.  You would need to add it to your layout ie your `RelativeLayout` that holds your other extended `View`.  Personally I would learn to do option 1 and use `Bitmaps` especially if this is a game.

What you could do though is make `smokeView` extend `ImageView` and override it `onDraw` method but you would still need to move the canvas.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take your advice, but that will only place it on the screen. I need to animate it's scale, alpha and position for the next second (and on every onDraw method call another instance of this animation should start in another place and go off in one second)

Comment: `Canvas.scale`... `Canvas.drawBitmap`... `Paint`...  don't mean to be funny but you do read the SDK yes?

Comment: Yes, I read it, and I understood what you told me. But that doesn't create an animation. I want to animate that sprite

Comment: Please give me an example of a circle animating it's position, or scale, or alpha. I really cannot see how that should animate. :|

Comment: Thank's. I was hoping for some tween animation where I set the first state, the final state, the duration, the interpolator and instantiate the animation. But it looks like Android is not Flash

Comment: @iuliux.  I changed the answer to use the built in animations.  The previous code is best used with a `SurfaceView`.  Have a look at the Lunar Lander SDK example to see how to use a `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help and for your time!